# Any rule of thumb in technical writing - conceptual cases

Tags: sentence-construction, writing, terminology

In technical writing, if someone writes as his first sentence in a "conceptual introduction"...

> 1. *One can reconstruct* a 3D wireframe model by fixing vertices where relevant edges meet.
> 2. *It can be reconstructed* a 3D wireframe model by fixing vertices where relevant edges meet.
> 3. *A 3D wireframe model* can be reconstructed by fixing vertices where relevant edges meet.

What would be most suitable (1, 2 , 3 or something else), or acceptable to the scientific community?

Is there any rule to be followed, especially in a situation like a conceptual introduction?

Comment: In this case, #3 is the best of the three, and that would be true even outside of technical writing. By the way, are you perchance doing research with [niro](http://ell.stackexchange.com/users/886/niro)?

Comment: @J.R. we are in a same team.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the rule of thumb is to remove anything that is not necessary from all sentences.

Sentence (2) is not grammatical.

In sentence (1) it is not necessary to indicate who is doing the reconstruction (**One** *can reconstruct*) and for that reason (*A ... model can be reconstructed*) is better.

But in sentence (3) edges only become *relevant* when they meet, so saying *relevant* is not necessary.

> A 3D wireframe model can be reconstructed by fixing vertices at all edge intersections.